# How to get hostname on a Cloud Run server from a request sent from a Firebase Hosting rewrite?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I need to do SSR on my web app. And since it's an international website, I need to know the domain (hostname) that is requesting the website so I can render in the appropriate language for the user.

Example:

```
https://www.mydomain.co.uk // WILL RENDER IN ENGLISH
https://www.mydomain.es    // WILL RENDER IN SPANISH
```

Here is the setup

- An **express server** on a Cloud Run docker Node.js container
- Firebase Hosting will **rewrite** all requests to the Cloud Run container

Here is how Firebase rewrites the traffic:

**firebase.json**

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "my-server-id",
          "region": "us-central1"
        }
      }
    ]
```

It's working fine. But I've noticed that all requests reach my Cloud Run server with the following hostname:

- `req.hostname === "https://my-server-id-on-cloud-run.run.app"`, which is default Cloud Run url for my server service.

I've noticed that Firebase Hosting adds my actual domain name to the following header:

- `x-forwarded-host: "https://www.mydomain.co.uk" OR "https://www.mydomain.es`

Is this the correct header to read my domain from? I didn't find any documentation on this subject.

If a user hits my website either using my app's Firebase default urls (`web.app OR firebaseapp.com`) or through a connected custom domain, I can count on the fact that the `x-forwarded-host` header **will always be there, correct?**

Could there be a situation where `x-forwarded-host` would contain **more than one** URL? Like it happens in the [`x-forwarded-for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) with IPs?

References:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-cloud-run-container

---

**PS:** I've noticed that if I hit my cloud run server directly from the Cloud Run default url `.run.app`, the `x-forwarded-for` header is not present, which makes sense, given the fact that it is a direct request, and not a rewritten one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Host),

1. This header could be the best option, given all the pros you share plus:

- `X-Forwarded-Host` header is useful to determine which Host was originally used.
- This header is used for debugging, statistics, and generating location-dependent content.

2. The **Syntax** is: `X-Forwarded-Host: <host>`, and the **Directive** is:

```
<host>
The domain name of the forwarded server.
```

This means that you can't have moew than 1 value in that header.